# How to consume PHP SOAP web service?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm working on a website project to consume a web service of a travel agency.
The future website will be a travel agence too wich contains the same hotels, rooms, etc as the source website.
So, i need to connect to their API, send the XML file genrerated in my website and then receive the response.

This is what i have :

**The travel agency api address:**

http://api.xxx.net/API/API.asmx

**Methods**

*GetHotels*: That methods list of available rooms for your seacrh criteria.

*MakeBooking*: That methods create booking for your booking request.

*GetBookingDetail*: That methods give your booking detail.

**ASP.Net sample code’s**

```
public void GetHotels()
{
    API.PASSENGER[] pass = new API.PASSENGER[3];
    pass[0] = new API.PASSENGER();
    pass[0].PASSTYPE = "ADT";
    pass[0].FIRSTNAME = "TEST";
    pass[0].LASTNAME = "test last name";
    pass[1] = new API.PASSENGER();
    pass[1].PASSTYPE = "ADT";
    pass[1].FIRSTNAME = "test 2";
    pass[1].LASTNAME = "test last name";
    pass[2] = new API.PASSENGER();
    pass[2].PASSTYPE = "CHD";
    pass[2].DOB = "16.06.2001";
    pass[2].FIRSTNAME = "TEST child";
    pass[2].LASTNAME = "test last name";
    API.SEARCH_REQUEST rq = new API.SEARCH_REQUEST();
    rq.AGENTINFO = new API.AGENT_INFO();
    rq.AGENTINFO.AGENT_ID = "agent login";
    rq.AGENTINFO.AGENT_PWD = " agent pass";
    rq.TOWNCODE = "";
    rq.CHECKINDATE = "02.09.2014";
    rq.CHECKOUTDATE = "08.09.2014";
    rq.HOTELCODE = "";
    rq.LANGUAGECODE = "TRK";
    rq.PASSENGERLIST = pass;
    Response.Write(rq.CHECKINDATE);
    Response.Write(rq.CHECKOUTDATE);
    API.API api = new API.API();

    API.SEARCH_RESPONSE[] test = api.GetHotels(rq);
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(test[i].ERRORINFO.ToString() + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].HOTELNAME + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].HOTELPICTURE + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].HOTELSHORTINFO + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].PLACECODE + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].PLACENAME + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].PRODUCTKEY + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].ROOMNAME + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].ROOMPRICE + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].CHECKINDATE + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].CHECKOUTDATE + "<br>");
        Response.Write(test[i].ROOMNAME + "<br>");
        Response.Write("<hr/>");


    }
}

public void MakeBooking()
{
    API.API api = new API.API();
    API.PASSENGER[] pass = new API.PASSENGER[3];
    pass[0] = new API.PASSENGER();
    pass[0].PASSTYPE = "ADT";
    pass[0].FIRSTNAME = "TEST";
    pass[0].LASTNAME = "test last name";
    pass[0].DOB = "dfss";
    pass[1] = new API.PASSENGER();
    pass[1].PASSTYPE = "ADT";
    pass[1].FIRSTNAME = "test 2";
    pass[1].LASTNAME = "test last name";
    pass[1].DOB = "16.03.1983";
    pass[2] = new API.PASSENGER();
    pass[2].PASSTYPE = "CHD";
    pass[2].DOB = "16.06.2001";
    pass[2].FIRSTNAME = "TEST child";
    pass[2].LASTNAME = "test last name";
    API.ROOM_DETAIL[] room = new API.ROOM_DETAIL[1];
    room[0] = new API.ROOM_DETAIL();
    room[0].CHECKINDATE = "02.09.2014";
    room[0].CHECKOUTDATE = "08.09.2014";
    room[0].HOTELCODE = "AP";
    room[0].PRODUCTKEY = "27-926-27677";

    API.BOOKING_REQUEST book = new API.BOOKING_REQUEST();
    book.AGENTINFO = new API.AGENT_INFO();
    book.CUSTOMERINFO= new API.CUSTOMER();
    book.AGENTINFO.AGENT_ID = " agent login ";
    book.AGENTINFO.AGENT_PWD = " agent pass";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.ADDRESS = "istanbul plaza";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.CITY = "istanbul";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.COUNTRY = "Turkey";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.EMAIL = "mert@xxx.com";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.FAX = "11111";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.FIRSTNAME = "API";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.LASTNAME = "API";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.PHONE = "222";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.PHONEMOBILE = "532";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.TITLE = "MR";
    book.CUSTOMERINFO.ZIP = "34768";
    book.LANGUAGECODE = "TRK";
    book.PASSENGERLIST = pass;
    book.ROOMDETAIL_LIST = room;

    API.BOOKING_RESPONSE bookResponse = api.MakeBooking(book);
    Response.Write(bookResponse.ERRORINFO + "<br>");
    Response.Write(bookResponse.BOOKINGSTATUS + "<br>");
    Response.Write(bookResponse.PNR + "<br>");
    Response.Write(bookResponse.TOTALCOMISSION + "<br>");
    Response.Write(bookResponse.TOTALAMOUNT + "<br>");
}
```

I don't know how to start. I could really use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: SOAP means XML over HTTP, following the standard.  So you'll create an XML request that conforms to the service WSDP, POST it with authorization headers set, and parse the response XML you get back.  You'll need a PHP XML parser: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php.  Better yet, Google for PHP SOAP libraries: http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Answer (score 0):

Using the WSDL from http://api.suaytur.net/API/API.asmx?WSDL, you could generate the corresponding package from [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) in order to be sure on how to structure your request in PHP as every element will be a PHP object with setters/getters. It uses the native PHP SoapClient class so you'll understand easily and quickly who to send these requests if you're familiar with PHP